# Why is the data not correctly fetched from the realtime database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

this is my code:

```
DatabaseReference starCountRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('temp/${widget._tmep}/temp');
    starCountRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      final snapshot = event.snapshot.value;
      if (snapshot != null) {
        Object? temp = snapshot;
        print(temp);
...
```

In the print statement, I receive the:

```
flutter: [null, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

But, my real-time database is the following:

[image]

It does not give me: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

When the Firebase SDKs find sequential, numeric values in keys they may interpret them as an array. That is exactly what you have here, the SDK interprets your boolean values as an array and adds an empty value at index 0.

There is no way to configure this behavior. A common workaround is to prefix the values with a short, alphanumeric prefix on the numeric values, e.g. `key_1`, `key_2`, etc.

Also see: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase).